# QtCreator debugger showing <not accessible> for QString

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

When a break point is hit, the values for QString variables in the "Locals and Expressions" window says "".

In fact it does this for all "Q types".

QtCreateor 3.1.2 (opensource)
Qt 5.3.1 
GCC 4.5.1, 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was an out of date GDB, the system install (/usr/bin/gdb) was 7.2

From: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-debugger-engines.html#supported-gdb-versions

“Starting with version 3.1,  The minimal supported version is GDB 7.4.1”

I built the GDB that shipped with QtCreator (but I’m not sure if this was actually required) 
http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtCreatorBuildGdb

And then updated the “kit” associated with the project to use the new debugger